# Change specific pose during an animation

Tags: animation

Great place to be, hope that you're all doing well.

I'm quite new to Blender, coming from "other" side.. And have stumbled upon a specific project that needs some fixes.

I have a character that is rigged and animated with specific movements that are all coming from one pose. Think of a person standing in one pose and talking, waving with hands, claping etc..

Well I want to change that main pose from which all other anims are starting. I just need arms area. The rest can stay unchanged.
I've tried with NNA, but its kind of a daunting task blending and replacing...especially since the anims seam to be baked. Probably from some mocap.
So, I was wondering if there is a better, more effective way to do it?
Please forgive for a bit of longer post, and or if I wasn't clear about something.
Thanks!